# Working with Iframes and PHP

Tags: php, iframe

I have several questions about php content in Iframe.

1. I want to create some navigation links and target the Iframe. Is there an easy way to do?
2. Do you think I can only do this with Ajax or Ahah ?
3. This is what I ve tried so far, but it does not work.

Here is my code.

```
      // HERE ARE NAVIGATION LINKS

        <header>
        <h1>Välkommen till Min Sida</h1><br>
            <nav>
                <a href="index.php?go=welcome">HOME</a>
                <a href="index.php?go=about">ABOUT ME</a>
                <a href="index.php?go=contact">CONTACT</a>
                <a href="index.php?go=subscribtion">SUBSCRIBE</a>
            </nav>
        </header>


    // HERE IS MY IFRAME WHERE I WANT TO OPEN MY PHP FILES  



<div class='content' >
  <iframe>

    <?php

$go = @$_GET["go"];

            switch($go){


    // IF I CLICK ON "WELCOME" FROM THE NAVIGATION BAR, OPEN THIS LINK IN My IFRAME

                case "welcome";
                include("welcome.php");
                break;


    // IF I CLICK ON "ABOUT" FROM THE NAVIGATION BAR, THIS LINK IN MY IFRAME





 case "about";
        include("newarrivals.php");
        break;


 // AS "DEFAULT", SHOW THIS IN THE IFRAME

    default;
    echo 

            <figure>
            <img src="figure.png"  alt="Figure 1" style="max-width:80%; height:auto;">
            <figcaption> <h6> Illustration: Mehmet Akb. </h6> </figcaption>
            </figure>

break;
}
?>

</iframe> 
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript to reload iframe

1. Move your iframe content to `icontent.php`
2. Add some ID into iframe `<iframe id="contentFrame"></iframe>`
3. Change your link action

   ```
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="goto('icontent.php?go=welcome')">HOME</a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="goto('icontent.php?go=about')">ABOUT ME</a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="goto('icontent.php?go=contact')">CONTACT</a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="goto('icontent.php?go=subscribtion')">SUBSCRIBE</a>
   ```
4. Create this javascript function

   ```
   function goto(url) {
       document.getElementById("contentFrame").contentWindow.location.replace(url);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you, It worked, but now my <div>  does not fit the size of my Iframe content. Do you know how to fix it? I tried everything but it doesnt work.

Comment: I can't replicate your unfit content size problem. Your old code is working fine on me. Please open new question, use fiddle to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If your Iframe has a name, you can use ***target*** property to determine the iframe name such as

```
<iframe name="topframe"></iframe>
<a href="xxx" target="topframe">
```